# docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details

Tags: docker

```
 docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-05-17 15:47:26 CEST; 17h ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 11843 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service

May 18 08:48:38 temp systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 18 08:49:09 temp systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
May 18 08:49:09 temp systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
May 18 08:49:09 temp systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 18 08:49:15 temp systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
May 18 08:49:15 temmp systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 18 09:00:03 temp systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
May 18 09:00:03 temp systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
May 18 09:03:51 temp systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
May 18 09:03:51 temp systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

Tried to uninstall docker and reinstalled it but it raises the same error is the docker daemon running can someone help me here.

Comment: You should add some information about OS, how you run docker ...

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `docker.service` file? Possible location: `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service`. Or `find /etc -name docker.service`

Comment: Please, post your docker version and linux version

Comment: Sorry for the delay in gettting back. Linux version: Ubuntu 16.04. Docker version: 18.03.1-ce

Comment: docker.service file.`[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
LimitNOFILE=1048576
`

Comment: `# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
# restart the docker process if it exits prematurely
`

Comment: `Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Answer (score 6):

There is a service that docker requires that is not running, thus, systemd won't launch docker.

Try launching `journalctl -f` (without `-u`) to see all unit logs, then start docker and read carefully the log, you will probably see some other units trying to start and failing.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the reason why docker isn't starting by running

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix://
```

In my case it was a fresh install of Centos7 with Docker 18.09

```
ERRO[2018-11-14T22:14:55.441548150+02:00] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay2
ERRO[2018-11-14T22:14:55.444930007+02:00] AUFS was not found in /proc/filesystems       storage-driver=aufs
ERRO[2018-11-14T22:14:55.447984399+02:00] 'overlay' not found as a supported filesystem on this host. Please ensure kernel is new enough and has overlay support loaded.  storage-driver=overlay
```

To fix that, I had to upgrade to a newer kernel, and remove the current docker storage

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Then docker started working

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem on my machine. I don't have success to solve this issue.
But if you are in a hury you can do

```
 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

All classic commands will work (docker system, docker etc..)